# Datetime Parameter in SSRS - input validation

Tags: sql-server, datetime, reporting-services

I have an input parameter 'StartDate' with datatype set as 'Date/Time'. Apart from using the calendar control, user can also enter values manually. I would like to know if there is any way to validate it so that the following error

> An error occurred during local report processing. The value provided
>   for the report parameter 'StartDate' is not valid for its type.

is not displayed when some junk value is provided as input. I saw a thread similiar to this [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cfa27e92-9b88-421f-9473-84b0a6cca63a/datetime-parameter-in-ssrs-manual-input-validation), 
and tried using custom code to validate the parameter value, still not working.

Is there a way to use Date/Time as datatype and still validate the value so that the error is not thrown?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: an exception do must be thrown if validation fail so you cannot get rid of the error message (and you do not want to...). unfortunately 'still not working' isn't a technical description useful to help you. what's going wrong? what did you try? where is failing? please post some code.

Comment: I added custom code to report properties and then added a textbox to display an error message in report designer.
And tried to access that function through textbox visibility which is available in textbox properties as shown below

=IIF(Code.FunctionName(Parameters!DateTimeName.Value),TRUE,FALSE)
Now it says, "The VisibilityHdden expression for the text box 'TextBoxName' contains an error:'FunctionName' is not a member of 'ReportExprHostImpl.CustomCodeProxy'."

Comment: FuntionName should be the name of the class you are trying to call here. Plus just to be sure you should be using VB as code behind. I am saying this because some people end up using C# before they realize that it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Error:

```
The value provided for the report parameter 'StartDate' is not valid for its type. (rsReportParameterTypeMismatch)
```

Change Your Date Format:
use this format to pass in parameter - "dd-MM-yyyy".
if format is not change then check your system date format.

Comment: when you selecting the date in reportviewer that time check the format shoulld be in "dd-MMM-yyyy" i.e "23-Sep-2014"

Answer (score 0):

Select Date Format
use this format to get result.

and i think your Date date format in 'MM-dd-yyyy' that is showing invalid

[image: Date Format]